# Problems with the drivers, mouse and display

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, mouse, display, brightness

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8 in my laptop. 
These are the issues I am facing after the installation:

1- I am not able to change the brightness of the screen.

2- The cursor keeps on blinking and sometimes disappear.

3- The resolution of my screen is 1368x786 but sometimes Ubuntu opens in a lower resolution.

4- After installing Ubuntu, during start-up its not asking to select OS. It directly opens Ubuntu.

Specs of my laptop:-

Lenovo ideapad z570

4GB RAM

500GB HDD

2nd gen i5

Nvidia 540M (2GB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following command to change the brightness:

```
echo 300 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

"300" is the level of brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Install the video card accelerated driver

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Reinstall the mouse driver

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```

Comment: I did. Still unable to change the brightness.